# Swagger2 @ApiParam specifying type

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to change the type of a parameter on the generated swagger contract, but it looks like the `@ApiParam#type` property is not working.

```
ResponseEntity<Void> delete(
        @ApiParam(
                value = "The id of the object",
                required = true,
                type = "java.lang.String") Integer id);
```

Doing this has no effect in swagger-ui, and id is still being shown as Integer.

Does anyone knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `@ApiImplicitParam`

```
@ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "string", name = "id")
ResponseEntity<Void> delete(Integer id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `"string"` not `"java.lang.String"`.

The annotation is not @ApiParam, you can use `@ApiImplicitParam`, and use `dataType="string"`

The supported type as below:

- integer
- long
- float
- double
- string
- byte
- boolean
- date
- dateTime

Comment: That was my first thought, but it doesn't work either